# Linq to XML, C#

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I have an xml in `XDocument` object (LINQ to XML).  I need to add the namespace to each Xelement/node in the Xdocument.

I dont want to add in the below way. beceause i already have the xml in xdoc.

```
XDocument xDoc = new XDocument(
new XElement(ns + "root",
new XElement(ns + "person",
new XAttribute("id", 1),
new XElement(ns + "firstname", "jack"),
```

Below is the format i have

```
<root>
  <person>1</person>
  <firstname>jack</firstname>
</root>
```

I want to convert it to this below format

```
<emp:root>
  <emp:person>1</emp:person>
  <emp:firstname>jack</emp:firstname>
</emp:root>
```

Comment: Where is the declaration of `ns`? Also, what do you mean you already have the XML in `xDoc`?

Comment: XNamespace ns = "http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom"; i loaded the xml string into xDocument object. Xdocument xDoc = New Xdocument(); xDoc.Parse(xml.tostring())

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
foreach (var node in xDoc.Descendants()) 
{ 
    node.Name = ns + node.Name.LocalName; 
}
```

That should work:

Side note the namespace will only appear on the root node.

Comment: thank you.. i was looking for something like below. <emp:root>
  <emp:person>1</emp:person>
  <emp:firstname>jack</emp:firstname>
</emp:root>. add emp: to each and every element.

Comment: here is the namespace. xmlns:emp="w3.org/2005/Atom"

Comment: @goutham: it's there. You don't need "emp:" at the start of each node.

Comment: @goutham, it's there it just doesn't appear.